# Does a heads up high priority notification in android wake up the screen on a locked device by default?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-wake-lock

Or do you have to implement your own logic for this using wakelocks for example?

Comment: Depends in what you mean by 'locked' - if a device is 'Dozing' (Marshmallow and up) then Wakelocks are ignored, and I believe notifications won't fire until the Doze maintenance window occurs

Comment: Sorry,i mean by locked, screen off and key locked